# Unable to load database file in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database file called MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db stored in my app/src/main/assets/databases folder.  I'm trying to open the file in a function of my main activity:

```
private ExerciseDb createDatabase(){
    final String inFileName = "/data/data/<mypackage>/databases/MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db";
    File dbFile = new File(inFileName);
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + ExerciseDb.DATABASE_NAME;
    // Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
    // Transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    try {
        while ((length = fis.read(buffer))>0){
            output.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }

    // Close the streams
    try {
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("error",e.toString());
    }
    ExerciseDb ret = new ExerciseDb(this);
    return ret;
}
```

But I get a file not found exception on the line:

```
 fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);
```

In every tutorial I look at this seems to be the correct path to access this file so I am not sure why its not working.  It's also strange because this exact code did work until I uninstalled the app on my phone and did a clean build and reinstalled the app from android studio

Comment: Just use [SQLiteAssetHelper](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-sqlite-asset-helper/) instead

Answer (score 0):

Try:

1. to use your package name (e.g., `com.example.package`) instead of `myactivity` in `/data/data/com.example.package/databases/MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db`
2. Use `mkdirs` for `/data/data/com.example.package/databases/`. I'm not sure that this directory exists by default.
3. Use file without extention (just a suggestion): MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db > MainExerciseDatabaseOne

Comment: could you explain what you mean by #2?

Comment: @Mike , create all parent directories before using `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 0):

Putting `MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db` in `app/src/main/assets/databases` will not make it auto copy to app database location (`/data/data/<mypackage>/databases/MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db`). The database is still in your app.

I have tried the same thing before (include a database). Here is how I do it.

Put `MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db` in `app/res/raw/`. Then, you can access the database through file stream and copy it to the app database location.

```
try{
    File db = new File(DB_PATH + ExerciseDb.DATABASE_NAME)
    InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.ExerciseDb)
    final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dbFile);
    final byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
        out.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
} catch (IOException ignored) {
}
```

Then, you can access it normally with `SQLiteOpenHelper` using `MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db` as name.

If you insist to use asset folder, you can try this. I did test it but it should work.

```
InputStream in = context.getResources().getAssets().open("MainExerciseDatabaseOne.db")
```